# industrial-grade - meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The future of PHP looks very bright. Leading platform vendors such as IBM, Oracle,
>   MySQL, Intel, and, most recently, Red Hat have all endorsed it. The new Collaboration
>   Project initiated by Zend Technologies rallies many leading companies and community
>   members around new open source initiatives aimed at taking PHP to the next
>   level by creating an **industrial-grade**, de facto standard PHP web application development
>   and deployment environment. The Project’s first two open initiatives are:

What does this word mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Industrial-grade is a term used to denote larger size, toughness and resilience. An example: a bulldozer is an industrial-grade form of a shovel.

In your example, the term is used more abstractly to imply a more robust PHP system, better than all existing PHP systems; rougher; tougher ... but the language here is just overblown sales talk without any real substance.